# ElementTree XML Parsing Python, Problem with XML structure

Tags: python, arrays, xml, elementtree

I have had a question about Elemttree parsing before and it was answered the next day. I am still not a pro in python and therefore need help once more.

```
<MiddleCommand xsi:type="SetEndPoseToleranceType" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
        <CommandID>19827</CommandID>
        <Tolerance>
            <XPointTolerance>3.0</XPointTolerance>
            <YPointTolerance>3.0</YPointTolerance>
            <ZPointTolerance>2.0</ZPointTolerance>
            <XAxisTolerance>2.0</XAxisTolerance>
            <ZAxisTolerance>2.0</ZAxisTolerance>
        </Tolerance>
    </MiddleCommand>
    <MiddleCommand xsi:type="MoveToType" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
        <CommandID>19828</CommandID>
        <MoveStraight>false</MoveStraight>
        <EndPosition>
            <Point>
                <X>528.65</X>
                <Y>33.8</Y>
                <Z>50.0</Z>
            </Point>
            <XAxis>
                <I>-0.7071067811865475</I>
                <J>-0.7071067811865477</J>
                <K>-0.0</K>
            </XAxis>
            <ZAxis>
                <I>0.0</I>
                <J>0.0</J>
                <K>-1.0</K>
            </ZAxis>
        </EndPosition>
    </MiddleCommand>
```

This is part of my XML file. I have been able to get my Values from different Command types and write them into classes.
The only thing that i cant manage to do is.
I want an array with Commands. So that i know the order which one is the first to happen
So ultimately the array should look something like this:

```
Array_Commands = []
Array_Commands[0] = SetEndPoseToleranceType
Array_Commands[1] = MoveToType
```

Obviously I want to loop through the XML and not create the Array by hand. I dont have any code regarding this problem so far.

I hope someone knows a simple solution.
Best regard and thank you all!

Comment: Please post the python code to parse and populate objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See below

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET


xml = '''<r><MiddleCommand xsi:type="SetEndPoseToleranceType" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
        <CommandID>19827</CommandID>
        <Tolerance>
            <XPointTolerance>3.0</XPointTolerance>
            <YPointTolerance>3.0</YPointTolerance>
            <ZPointTolerance>2.0</ZPointTolerance>
            <XAxisTolerance>2.0</XAxisTolerance>
            <ZAxisTolerance>2.0</ZAxisTolerance>
        </Tolerance>
    </MiddleCommand>
    <MiddleCommand xsi:type="MoveToType" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
        <CommandID>19828</CommandID>
        <MoveStraight>false</MoveStraight>
        <EndPosition>
            <Point>
                <X>528.65</X>
                <Y>33.8</Y>
                <Z>50.0</Z>
            </Point>
            <XAxis>
                <I>-0.7071067811865475</I>
                <J>-0.7071067811865477</J>
                <K>-0.0</K>
            </XAxis>
            <ZAxis>
                <I>0.0</I>
                <J>0.0</J>
                <K>-1.0</K>
            </ZAxis>
        </EndPosition>
    </MiddleCommand></r>'''

root = ET.fromstring(xml)
cmds = [cmd.attrib['{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance}type'] for cmd in root.findall('.//MiddleCommand')]
print(cmds)
```

output

```
['SetEndPoseToleranceType', 'MoveToType']
```